# Радость и отрада. Безрадостный и безотрадный. Какова разница в значениях этих слов?

Tags: грамотная-речь, этимология, значение-слов, литература

> **РА́ДОСТЬ**, *-и, ж*.
>
> 1. Чувство удовольствия, удовлетворения.
>
>    *[Батюшка] в тот же день прогнал [француза] со двора, к неописанной **радости** Савельича.* Пушкин, Капитанская дочка. *От **радости**, что ее взяли гулять, она [Каштанка] прыгала, бросалась с лаем на вагоны --- и гонялась за собаками.* Чехов, Каштанка. *Скоро начнется рабочий день — день труда и учебы, творческих **радостей**, и поисков, и достижений.* Катерли, Бронзовая прялка.
>
> **ОТРА́ДА**, *-ы, ж*.
>
> 1. Чувство удовольствия, радости, удовлетворения.
>    *Одинок я — нет **отрады**: Стены голые кругом.* Лермонтов, Узник. *[Василиса Перегриновна:] Жаль мне вас, благодетельница! Не дождетесь вы себе в этой жизни **отрады**! Вы всем благодеяния рассыпаете, а чем вам платят за это?* А. Островский, Воспитанница.
>
> *[Словарь русского языка А. П. Евгеньевой]*

---

Исходя из определений эти слова значат в точности одно и то же: *«чувство удовольствия, удовлетворения»*.

Однако «отрада» содержит приставку «от-»:

> **Отрада**
> ...
> Приставка: **от-**; корень: **-рад-**; окончание: **-а**.
>
> *[[Викисловарь](https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%BE%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B0)]*

Как меняет эта приставка значение корня «-рад-»?

Какова разница между словами «радость» и «отрада»?

---

От этих слов есть производные слова «безрадостный» и «безотрадный»:

> **БЕЗРА́ДОСТНЫЙ**, *-ая, -ое; -тен, -тна, -тно*. Лишенный радости; невеселый. Безрадостная жизнь. □ *Дни потянулись серые и **безрадостные**.* Шолохов, Тихий Дон.
>
> **БЕЗОТРА́ДНЫЙ**, *-ая, -ое; -ден, -дна, -дно*. Не содержащий отрады, радости; унылый, мрачный. Безотрадное положение. Безотрадная жизнь. □ *Каркает ворон над белой равниною, Нищий в деревне за дровни цепляется. Этой сплошной безотрадной картиною Сердце подавлено, взор утомляется.* Н. Некрасов, Пожарище.
>
> *[Словарь русского языка А. П. Евгеньевой]*

---

Например:

> Хлопоты по ферме росли с каждым днем — хлопоты **безотрадные**,
> бестолковые.
>
> *И. С. Тургенев. Отцы и дети.*

Можно ли заменить, например, в этом предложении «безотрадные» на «безрадостные» без потери смысла: 
*«Хлопоты по ферме росли с каждым днем — хлопоты **безрадостные**, бестолковые»*?

Или всё-таки есть разница?

---

Как приставка «от-» влияет на значение корня «-рад-» в словах «отрада» и «безотрадный»?

Каково вообще происхождение слова «отрада»?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. **Радость** – это  чувство, которое сопровождается душевным подъемом, то есть его общая характеристика.  Для радости  обычно есть основания, но бывает  и беспричинная радость.

**Слово «отрада»**  имеет определенные особенности – это нечто,  чем душу отводят. Имеется в виду какой-то предмет, доставляющий радость даже в тех случаях, когда других причин для радости нет.

Здесь, кстати, видно и значение **приставки ОТ** – отвести эмоции в сторону радости.

Слова «отрада, безотрадный»   выглядят устаревающими, поэтому возможно их использование в ироническом или высоком стилях.

2. ***Хлопоты по ферме росли с каждым днем — хлопоты безотрадные, бестолковые***.

Думаю, что замена нежелательна, хотя возможна.  Хлопоты  вообще вещь беспокойная, так что ждать от них радости не приходится.  Но иногда бывают приятными, если с ними связать какое-то радостное событие. А если сделать это не получается, то  хлопоты называют  безотрадными,  **особо подчеркивая это** (унылые, тягостные).

**Словарный материал**

**ОТРАДА;** ж. 1. Чувство удовольствия, радости, удовлетворения. Найти отраду для души. Найти отраду в чём-л. 2. Тот, кто (то, что) доставляет удовольствие, радость. О. души, сердца. Чтение - моя о. Поездки - моя единственная о. в этой жизни. * Живёт моя отрада В высоком терему (Народная песня).

У Даля: **ОТРАДА** ж. утеха, услада, утешенье, успокоенье, наслажденье; на чем или чем душу отводят, что покоит, услаждает, облегчает бремя, скорбь. Дети отрада моя. Ищи отрады в молитве. Пьянице одна отрада: вино. Только и отрады, как боль немного отпустит. Толковый словарь Даля

**БЕЗОТРАДНЫЙ.** Не содержащий ничего отрадного; унылый, тягостный. Б-ое положение. Б-ая жизнь. Б-ые воспоминания, перспективы. Б. вид новых кварталов.

**БЕЗРАДОСТНЫЙ**,  Не содержащий ничего радостного; невесёлый, унылый. Б-ое детство. Б. пейзаж. Б-ая картина разрушений.

Comment: Зачем вы привели словарные статьи, хотя они уже были в моём вопросе? Первое словарное определение вообще один в один совпадает, третье и четвёртое мало  чем отличается. Что вы хотели этим сказать?

Comment: Просто я пользовалась другими словарями, в том числе словарем Даля.  Так что вы не обращайте внимания. У вас есть вопросы по содержанию?

Comment: _«Хлопоты вообще вещь беспокойная, так что ждать от них радости не приходится»._ Тогда бы не было смысла называть их безотрадными, если они и так не могут приносить радости. У Ожегова есть определение хлопот без негативной оценки: «длительные занятия, связанные с многочисленными заботами». Тургенев, скорей всего, имел в виду, что работы по хозяйству могут приносить удовольствие, но в данном случае работы были бестолковые и соответственно не приносили удовлетворения.

Comment: Кроме Даля никто не даёт определения радости, как _«утеха, услада, утешенье, успокоенье, наслажденье; на чем или чем душу отводят, что покоит, услаждает, облегчает бремя, скорбь»_, но, скорее всего, это правильное определение. Не понятно, почему более новые словари дают другое определение, не отличающееся от радости.

Comment: Все написанное - это мое мнение как носителя языка на современном этапе. Значение слова можно считать с его морфемного состава. Безотрадные?  Это значит,  что  в них только обычное беспокойство, всегда связанное с хлопотами, а повода для какой-либо радости (отрады)  нет никакой, сколько ни ищи. Повторяю, что это мое мнение. Надеюсь, что будут другие  ответы и мнения, и у вас будет возможность их сравнить, а также высказать свое личное понимание  этих слов. Именно это интересно.

Comment: К Далю у меня в данном случае много доверия, так как слово устаревает, а ему было виднее его изначальный смысл. Отрада - это та радость, которая "отводит" нас от печали,  беспокойства, хлопот.

Comment: Жаль, что этимологические словари не дают объяснения происхождения слова «отрада», но, вероятно, Даль прав. Отрада — это, получается, синоним утешения, только с более сильным позитивным значением. Нашёл в Толковом словаре Ушакова: _«**уте́шить** — успокоить кого-н., **доставить отраду кому-н.**, облегчить кому-н. горе, тревогу (советом, участием)»_. Таким образом, это близкие по значению слова.

Comment: Проголосовал и принял ответ.

Comment: Спасибо. вопрос был интересным.

Comment: _«Это значит, что в них только обычное беспокойство, всегда связанное с хлопотами, а повода для какой-либо радости (отрады) нет никакой, сколько ни ищи»_ — может вы и правы, но я тут не уверен. _«Отрада — это та радость, которая „отводит“ нас от печали, беспокойства, хлопот»_ — а это, скорей всего, правильно.

Comment: Нет, скорей всего, в «отраде» предлог «от-» в другом смысле: отрада — то, что ПРОИСХОДИТ ОТ РАДОСТИ.

Comment: @Егор Сальков Отрада – от радости? Как это можно понять? (1) Разновидность радости (2) То, что уводит нас от радости. Оба варианта так себе, неважнец :)) В первом случае сущность отрады не раскрыта, а второй вообще не подходит.

Comment: Да понимайте это как можете :))

Comment: Это вы мне или автору вопроса? :)))